# Solr sort on a dynamic column

Tags: solr

I want to solve a problem related to sorting based on products in a category:

I have 3 tables

Product

```
|-------id----------|-----name-------|
|       p1          |      Prod 1    |
|       p2          |      Prod 2    |
|       p3          |      Prod 3    |
|       p4          |      Prod 4    |
|       p5          |      Prod 5    | 
|-------------------|----------------|
```

Category

```
|-------id----------|-----name-------|
|       c1          |      Cat 1     |
|       c2          |      Cat 2     |
|       c3          |      Cat 3     |
|       c4          |      Cat 4     |
|-------------------|----------------|
```

Product_Category

```
|-----prod id-------|-----cat id-----|----score----|
|       p1          |      c1        |     120     |
|       p1          |      c2        |     130     |
|       p2          |      c1        |     150     |
|       p2          |      c3        |     120     |
|       p2          |      c2        |     140     |
|       p3          |      c2        |     180     |
|       p3          |      c3        |     160     |
|-------------------|----------------|-------------|
```

This means I have products listed in multiple categories.
I have a generate listing page dynamically for each category by solr query.

Currently my solr doc looks like

```
{
    product_id:p1,
    category_id:[c1, c2]
}
```

The challenge I am facing now is I need to support sorting based on product category weight, i.e. listing page of c1 will have products p2, p1 in order and listing of c3 will be p3, p2, p1 (descending order of score)

If I change the schema like to doc look like

```
{
    product_id:p1,
    category_id:[c1, c2],
    c1_weight: 120,
    c2_weight: 130
}
```

This way I need to add a field cx_weight to schema every time we add a new category so that I can sort by cx_weight field.

Let me know a solution where I can use solr sort mechanism to sort by category weight and need not change schema every time I add a category.

Thanks
Dheerendra

Answer (score 2):

Why not try modeling your solr doc as a Product_Category row?

```
{
    product_id:p1,
    category_id:c1,
    weight:120
},
{
    product_id:p1,
    category_id:c2,
    weight:130
}
```

This will support your category-page requirements.

The only complicating factors appear if you search for some product attribute and need to de-duplicate across categories (see [field-collapsing doc](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) for this)

Comment: The reason is product has many other fields I will need to query on like price, weight, shipping free etc then these fields will also repeat in every document. I general the above technique makes the system heavy, if I had 1M products in my system and on an average if a product can be associated to 5 categories then I will have 5M documents just for the sake of 2 fields changing i.e. category_id and weight.

Comment: Lucene encodes field values with a symbol table like a column store.  In general, duplication of data isn't as problematic as with a relational DB.

Comment: You can also look into Solr's join functionality to see if you can do a simple Product joined with product/category, but it'll take a bit more work.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I use join in this case.

Comment: Sorry.  Pretty sure Join won't work in your scenario.  Best practice is to denormalize, as above.

Comment: If I am de-normalizing I would rather follow
{
    product_id:p1,
    category_id:[c1, c2],
    c1_weight: 120,
    c2_weight: 130
} so that number of docs reduce and add a column using sole API whenever a new classification is created.